# In discord.py, how do i check which button was clicked? Discord Bot

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, discord.py, chatbot

In this code, the variable interaction comes out as a weird computer omitted element. I want to know which button was clicked, so that I can check whether the button the user clicked was the correct one.

````
if f==1:
      await ctx.send("What was the color next to the word "+word_1+"?", components = [
        [Button(label=":"+color_1+"_circle: "+color_1.upper(),style="3", custom_id="button1"), Button(label=":"+color_2+"_circle: "+color_2.upper(), style="3", custom_id="button2"), Button(label=":"+color_3+"_circle: "+color_3.upper(), style="3", custom_id="button3")]
        ])
      answer=color_1
    if f==2:
      await ctx.send("What was the color next to the word "+word_2+"?", components = [
        [Button(label=":"+color_1+"_circle: "+color_1.upper(),style="3", custom_id="button1"), Button(label=":"+color_2+"_circle: "+color_2.upper(), style="3", custom_id="button2"), Button(label=":"+color_3+"_circle: "+color_3.upper(), style="3", custom_id="button3")]
        ])
      answer=color_2
    if f==3:
      await ctx.send("What was the color next to the word "+word_3+"?", components = [
        [Button(label=":"+color_1+"_circle: "+color_1.upper(),style="3", custom_id="button1"), Button(label=":"+color_2+"_circle: "+color_2.upper(), style="3", custom_id="button2"), Button(label=":"+color_3+"_circle: "+color_3.upper(), style="3", custom_id="button3")]
        ])
      answer=color_3
    #interaction = await bot.wait_for("button_click",timeout=7)
    #await interaction.send(content = "Button clicked!", ephemeral=False)
    #def check(x):
      #return x.author!=bot.user and x.author==ctx.author
    try:
      interaction = await bot.wait_for("button_click",timeout=7, check = lambda i: i.custom_id=="button1" or i.custom_id=="button2" or i.custom_id=="button3")
    
      await interaction.send(ctx.custom_id)
      #msg = await bot.wait_for('message', timeout=15, check=check)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
      a=random.randint(1,20)
      await ctx.send("Too late! You will now face a consequence.")

    else:
      answeru=""
      
      print(interaction)
      if interaction==answer:
        a=random.randint(20,100)
        print(a)
        await ctx.send(":white_check_mark: Good job!")
        a+=users[str(user.id)]["WLuck"]
        print(a)
        #a=4```
````

Comment: what does that mean?

Comment: @jsotola  sorry have to ping you to notify you

Comment: @jsotola oh i see what you mean it pasted incorrectly here, I have all the syntax and formatting right, I just need to know how to see which button was clicked after the "bot.wait_for("button_click) etc

Answer (score 0):

By using this code you can listen for interactions with [components](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/message-components) like buttons and context menus

```
@bot.event
async def on_component(ctx):
    # your code here
```

Comment: Thank you! But how would I implement it in a command?

Comment: Unfortunately, i don't know a way to implement component detection in a command. However you can try moving the code that comes after the check you want inside this event.

Comment: Alright thank you for trying :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    if f==1:
      await ctx.send("What was the color next to the word "+word_1+"?", components = [
        [Button(label=":"+color_1+"_circle: "+color_1.upper(),style="3", custom_id="button1"), Button(label=":"+color_2+"_circle: "+color_2.upper(), style="3", custom_id="button2"), Button(label=":"+color_3+"_circle: "+color_3.upper(), style="3", custom_id="button3")]
        ])
      answer=color_1
    if f==2:
      await ctx.send("What was the color next to the word "+word_2+"?", components = [
        [Button(label=":"+color_1+"_circle: "+color_1.upper(),style="3", custom_id="button2"), Button(label=":"+color_2+"_circle: "+color_2.upper(), style="3", custom_id="button2"), Button(label=":"+color_3+"_circle: "+color_3.upper(), style="3", custom_id="button3")]
        ])
      answer=color_2
    if f==3:
      await ctx.send("What was the color next to the word "+word_3+"?", components = [
        [Button(label=":"+color_1+"_circle: "+color_1.upper(),style="3", custom_id="button3"), Button(label=":"+color_2+"_circle: "+color_2.upper(), style="3", custom_id="button2"), Button(label=":"+color_3+"_circle: "+color_3.upper(), style="3", custom_id="button3")]
        ])
      answer=color_3

@buttons.click
async def button1(ctx):
    #write the code of button 1

...... #then write the code of button 2

#be careful on the custom id
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).